# rewrite the new line with old line in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to the node.js. So, I am reading a file line by line

```
var lr = new LineByLineReader(fileName);
var prevLine = '';

lr.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});

lr.on('line', function (line) {
    res.removeHead(prevLine);

    // here when new line found i need to remove the previous response from the written response.
    res.write(line); 
    prevLine = line;
});

lr.on('end', function () {
   res.write(lineString+']');
    res.end();
});
```

is it possible to remove the written response.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to remove it, why write it in the first place? Ultimately, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the response. i am reading a large file and writing line by line to the server and my front end reads the writing data, for next call i dont want to get the previous data.

Comment: Could you clarify "for next call i dont want to get the previous data"? Have you had this happen when running your code? If so, could you include the client side code? A more complete snippet of server side code might help also.